# How does deviantart dynamically add new content on page depending on width of browser window?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Go to http://deviantart.com and scroll down and check the area where it says "you are viewing daily deviations." If you widen your browser window enough, new content appears (another drawing appears) and everything is centered nicely in your browser. How does deviantart do this?

I tried to create a div with a set height and overflow set to hidden, so this way, when the browser is increased, new content shows. However, the problem with this is that it doesn't center the content. So when the browser is a certain size, there is an ugly margin on the right side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think they are using flexible width and sizes for containers (the one you specify with %). It is probably called fluid layout or something.

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Using_Percent

Comment: Yes I tried that. It works, but the only problem I'm having is I'm unable to make it centered. The reason is that whenever content overflows the browser window, the div stays left-aligned in the browser window even when using text-align: center. This causes an ugly right margin when I'd just like for the content to be centered.

Comment: @user594623 use a div.wrapper with auto margins or (ugly solution) wrap the content in the 2nd column of a 3 column <table> with auto width

Comment: anyway you can give me sample code? I tried your method, but it still won't center my content. Remember the deviantart site hides stuff when the browser window is too small. Whenever my div goes to hide, the elements that are in view stay left-aligned.